# Is there any way in python to find size of a image in html?

Tags: python, html, css, image, xpath

Source code of a page is all I have.

```
tree = etree.HTML(source_page_text)
image_list = tree.xpath('//img[@src]')
```

By using xpath, I can find all the 'img' tag with a 'src' attribute as above. But information of size of a image are in css. In javascript, I can find the size easily by using e.g.

```
document.querySelectorAll("img")[83].height
```

since it is an object.

So how do I find the size of a image in python?

Comment: If you want to get the info from css file you might want to parse it instead. Or you could just download the image and get its dimensions if it'll fit your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on the server and not in the browser, you'll have to (re)download the image and use a library like PIL to get its size.

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
import io

def image_size(url)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
       f = io.BytesIO(u.read())
       img = Image.open(f)
       return img.size # (width, height) tuple
```

**NOTE**: You'll need the [PIL(pillow fork)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/) library installed on your system.

Another option is to download the style sheets and use a parser like [tinycss](https://tinycss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to try and correlation css rules with selectors to derive the size. I think this would be tricky though.

Answer (score 0):

Python itself does not provide means to render web pages applying stylesheets, scripts etc.

You could try to use GUI frameworks that have a webbrowser built in (PyQt, PyGTK) that allow execution of JS code in corresponding widgets.